# FCM XMPP interface with VAPID

Tags: firebase, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging, vapid

Is is possible to use the Firebase Cloud Messing XMPP interface with VAPID?

I tried to do it, but as soon as I register my javascript client with messaging.usePublicVapidKey('') I get a DEVICE_UNREGISTERED error from the FCM XMPP interface.

Has anyone done that and can point me in the right direction?